# Reference of component

Tags: transistors, pcb, diodes, packages, reference

I´m trying to repair my lock control in my car. And this board seems like the problem, so I want create a new board (exactly the same) based on this. But I facing a challenge:

I cant determine what component are this tree elements that seem like transistors:

1) and 3) The first one and the thrird has a label in the PCB that say: Q1 (like a transistor). In the package device the label say: CIP

2) The second device has a label that say: D3, like a diode (but have 3 terminals). In the package device the label say: A4M

The image of the circuit:

[image]

Of course I need to find the correct element reference to put this on my new board.

If someone hear can tell me the reference of this three components, I´ll be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Q1 and Q2's collector terminals go to one terminal of each relay.

The D3 package is a dual diode, clamping each collector to the common relay terminal. BAV70 has marking A4, but I don't know what M means, though W would mean made in China.